# How is rate of radioactive decay constant?

Tags: radioactivity, half-life

If I understand correctly, the rate of radioactive decay depends on the amount of the radioactive element. How then can it be constant, if it depends on concentration?

Comment: What is constant is the _fraction_ of the remaining atoms of the isotope in question that will decay in a given interval of time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE. What's constant is $\lambda$ in $\dot{N}=-\lambda N$, but this still implies $\dot{N}\propto N$.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.                           
                                                                                                                I understand  that lambda is constant, but lambda is decay constant, not decay rate right?

Comment: $dN/dt$ is the decay rate or activity.

Comment: What we really mean when we say that the decay rate is constant is that $\frac{d \log N}{dt}$ is constant, i.e. the infinitesimal *relative* change in $N$ is constant.

Answer (score 6):

The rate of radioactive decay depends on the statistical probability that any random *single* nucleus will decay in a unit of time. That probability does not depend on the number of atoms present in a sample, which is a piece of information that the nucleus of an atom does not have any sort of access to in the first place.

But the *number of decays* that occur in a chunk of material in a unit of time will depend on the *number of nuclei present* in a sample. If you double the number of nuclei in a sample, you double the number of nuclei in that sample which will decay in a unit of time, *on the average*.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, physicist are rarely exact in their wording. Thus, it would help if you added a reference. From the context it's usually clear what people mean. Here are two contexts:

1. In the equation
   $$
   N_{decay}(t) = N_{0} \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot t}
   $$
   the *decay constant* $\lambda$ has the unit of a rate, i.e. $1/time$. This is why it might be referenced as "decay rate". Thus, some people might express $\lambda = const$ by saying that the decay rate is constant.
2. An alternative representation uses the half life time period $t_{1/2} = \frac{\ln(2)}{\lambda}$. E.g. [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Nuclear_Chemistry/Nuclear_Kinetics/Radioactive_Decay_Rates) they say "The rate of decay remains constant throughout the decay process." What they trying to express is $t_{1/2} = const$.

Comment: Thank you very much; that was insightful.